# Why is everybody suddenly scared of me at Lady Boyle's Last Party?

Tags: dishonored

I am at Lady Boyle's Last Party, I have an invitation and everything. After taking great pains to blend in with the guests, and quietly incapacitating most of the waitstaff and the watchman guarding the service stairs (by the rum fountain), I snuck upstairs to loot the joint. As far as I know, I was never spotted while I was up there, and I stashed all the watchmen's bodies in the attic where they couldn't be found.

However, when I come back downstairs, people start freaking out at the sight of me. I figured one of them must have seen me upstairs somehow, but after reloading my save a few times, I'm not so sure. I've re-loaded the same save several times, and sometimes everyone gets scared as soon as I come out of the service stair doorway, sometimes it doesn't happen until a few minutes later. It seems to be one of the Boyle sisters who notices me first each time but I can't say for sure. However, I've only talked to each sister once.

So, any idea what's going on? I've already finished the mission by slowing time, choking the appropriate sister, then Blinking her down to the basement, that allowed me to get away without killing anyone but I was still Detected even though I wouldn't have been otherwise. Just curious.

Comment: Are they running in terror or complaining about your weapon?

Comment: They're running (or cowering) in terror and I'm being killed by the Watchmen and Overseers. I put my weapons away while I was still upstairs. At some point after re-joining the party, one or more of the guests "Detects" me (1, 2, then 3 lightning bolts above their head, finally turning red) and that's that. But as I said, sometimes it takes minutes for that to happen, even if all I'm doing in the meantime is walking around the party, even talking to other guests.

Comment: I didn't even realise you could _get_ an invitation till my second playthrough. What a great game :D

Comment: @Alex there are in fact two different ways to get invitations, one in the level itself, one in a previous level!

Comment: @BenBrocka ZOMG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone sees you while you're trespassing (upstairs) everyone will turn hostile (one person seeing you = everyone, oddly enough), I'd bet that's what's happening. It can be tricky to come back downstairs without being spotted (even when using tricks like timestop and blink people seem to see me). Note that you can totally kill/knock out the upstairs guards without alerting everyone else if you're careful; every playthrough I've done I've KOed or killed the guards upstairs and I usually get out scott-free.

Try exiting the downstairs via a more discrete way: you can leave via the balcony (the door to the outside from the first bedroom after the stairs) and the guard outside won't "detect" you (he's also easy to knock out or kill, but it's pretty unnecessary). He just politely asks you to stop trespassing. Drop gracefully from the balcony and no one should turn hostile (note that falling on someone's head, as I did the first time, counts as an attack).

Also note the basement, oddly, doesn't count as trespassing, so I'd poke around all the "safe" areas before going upstairs, and making a real save before going upstairs, since it's usually when things go south in this mission.

Comment: Is there also a safe way to move from the Attic down to the first floor/basement? I was thinking there was but I'm not sure, I might be thinking of a path to one of the bedrooms instead.

Comment: I've only played through that level twice, so this isn't representative in any way: The first time I played through it, I killed every guard I met upstairs without being detected, but was detected instantly as soon as I returned downstairs (through the main entrance, by leaving through the balcony). The second time, I went upstairs but neither killed nor subdued any guard. Upon returning downstairs, people acted as if nothing happened. My guess is that by attacking anybody - seen or not - people will turn hostile towards you.

Comment: @Nolonar you can totally kill the upstairs guards and be undetected, I've done it a few times. It's the damn guards/people outside the exit of the "trespassing" zone that seem to always get me. It *is* possible to get past those as well though.

Comment: I actually thought at one point that the guests were reacting to the rat blood on my sword (even though I had it sheathed), thinking I had killed someone..

Comment: @DanC can rat blood get on your sword? To my horror by the end of my non-lethal playthrough my sword had blood on it and I had no idea why. It was clean through 75% of the playthrough.

Comment: It definitely can get on your sword ,whether the blood actually shows up or not might have to do with the number of rats killed per unit time, in that mission I ran into a rat swarm in the basement and hacked most of them to pieces and my sword was bloody afterwards. I've never checked to see if killing just one rat will do it though.

Answer (score 2):

It appers that it's just a bug, triggered by who knows what. Boyle sisters mission seems to be preatty messy, lots of bugs have been found by players. I had that problem too and I was never seen nor guards where found unconscious. Stealing shouldn't be a problem since I've stolen tons of stuff before and never had problem with guards going randomly aggro. Besides it would be contrary to the philosofy of the game. If they didn't see you, you didn't do it.
So, sadly, just a bug. I'm going to sart the mission again nad trying to avoid going upstairs...

Answer (score 1):

Stealing is also a problem. If you steal too much some staff may become hostile to you and that will cause problems. Also some guests will become aggressive if you are around them too much and they recognize you.